# Notion of being Hilbert-Schmidt for multilinear bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

If $U_0$ and $H$ are separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces, then a bounded linear operator $\Phi:U_0\to H$ is called *Hilbert-Schmidt* $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\left\|\Phi\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U_0,\:H)}^2:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|\Phi e_0^n\right\|_H^2<\infty\tag 1$$ for any orthonormal basis $(e_0^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $U_0$. $(1)$ is well-defined, cause we can show that its value doesn't depend on the choice of $(e_0^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

Let $\mathfrak L(A,B)$ denote the space of bounded linear operators from $A$ to $B$ and suppose $\Psi\in\mathfrak L(U_0,\mathfrak L(U_0,H))$. I've found the symbol sequence $\left\|\Psi\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}(U_0,\:H)}$ in some papers I've read, e.g. in [*A Runge–Kutta type scheme for nonlinear stochastic
partial differential equations with multiplicative trace
class noise*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1889) in equation (2.6), without a definition.

I suppose the notion of being *Hilbert-Schmidt* can be defined for multilinear bounded operators too, but it's not clear to me how exactly $\left\|\Psi\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}(U_0,\:H)}$ is defined.

One option would be $$\left\|\Psi\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}(U_0,\:H)}^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|(\Psi e^n_0)e_0^n\right\|_H^2\;.\tag 2$$ Especially for $Q\in\mathfrak L(U_0,\mathfrak L(V_0,H))$, where $V_0$ is another separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, another reasonable option would be $$\left\|Q\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}}^2:=\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|(Q e_0^m)f_0^n\right\|_H^2\tag 3\;,$$ where $(f_0^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V_0$.

> So, what's the actual definition of $\left\|\Psi\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}(U_0,\:H)}$ and $\left\|Q\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{(2)}}$?